# Laravel 5.2 - modify a model's builder

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

So, I am using Laravel's built in soft Deletes and I have run into an issue. When I call `withTrashed()` it returns a query builder object. This would be fine for most cases but after I call this I then want to call a method like `filter($this->filters)` which is specific to the MODEL and I no longer have access to now that I only have a query builder.

The reverse relationship also does not work as `withTrashed()` also wants a model where any kind of parsing method I can think of would return the model's query builder.

So I was hoping to find a way to modify a model object with where clauses so I can add my filters and send the model to `withTrashed()` WITH the filters in place. I am honestly not sure how to do this. Worst case scenario I can have the filter method return the query builder without any global scopes and add the `withTrashed()` query on to the end manually.

So the end result would be something like this:

`$model->filter($this->filters)->withTrashed();`

Im not trying to get a giant collection and whittle it down. Even with chunking when you have a few million rows it can get slow really quick, especially when you bring in filtering. Technically, for a one off, I could just add multiple `->where()` clauses to the query builder before i call `->get()` but that would mean doing custom filtering in every controller's index. So i am looking to abstract it as a method in the model that parses filters sent in and adds them to the model (this is the part im not sure on. Kind of like: github.com/marcelgwerder/laravel-api-handler

Any ideas?

Comment: `->filter()` works on collections so they will only be useful after a query is already executed.  Can you not just add a `->where()` condition chained to the `withTrashed` call as in the example [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models) ? That should run before the query is executed which is better anyway

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear. I meant to build a custom filter() method on the base Model class I created. I am NOT intending to use the collection filter method or any other collection method. Also, I am trying to abstract out this functionality so that I do not have to define custom where clauses on every endpoint that calls multiple objects in my entire api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for query scopes. You can create a new query scope on your model, and then it can be used like any other query builder method.

For example, to create a `filter()` scope:

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    public function scopeFilter($query, $filters) {
        // modify $query with your filters

        return $query;
    }
}
```

With that query scope defined, you call it like any other query builder method:

```
$data = \App\MyModel::withTrashed()->filter(/* your filters */)->get();
```

You can read more about [query scopes here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes).

Comment: Works great, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Filter is a method for a collection, as you can see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-filter

To make that returns a collection you should use a method like get(), as you can see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models

```
$yourVar = \App\YourModel::withTrashed()->get();
```

You will be able to filter in $yourVar after that! Or use where() method to get collection filtered by the query

```
 $yourVar = \App\YourModel::withTrashed()->where('active = 1')->get();
```

In both, $yourVar will be a Collection of results returned by get() method

Comment: I apologize. I mentioned `filter()` but did not specify that im actually trying to make a custom filter method on my base model that will parse through filters from the request and add appropriate where / wherehas filters to the model's query builder. I am not trying to use the `filter()` method provided by the collection because my data sets will be too large

Comment: Maybe you already know it, but you can process your data in parts, using chunk method. If this still not helping, i think that i don't understand enough what you need to help, you was so generic!

Comment: Humm, sorry bro, now i get what you need, but i don't know how help you with this :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if already has this problem, but i think that i figured out a way to do it. Using Eloquent's Global Scopes (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#global-scopes)

Soft deletes in fact are a global scope.

You will create an implementation for Scope class, then you will create a apply method that will perform the where clause.

Finally in your model you will override the boot method to say that this Model uses this global scope, every query in this Model will be performed in this way.

In the doc link there is a example of how do it and more explanations from Laravel creator.

Hope that this help!

-------- Edit --------

I see now that already has a solution, but maybe this way may be better for you or not, or for other, anyway, just another approach!